# Set does not work in velocity

Tags: java, velocity

Looks like set does not work in velocity when written as below :

```
#set (${modifier} = "some")
```

It works if I do `#set ($modifier = "some")`. Any reason for this?

**EDIT** : It doesn't work means no variable is set.

Comment: Could you elaborate what "does not work" is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because ${varname} is not a valid variablename in velocity as defined in the [reference manual](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#variables)

I am also often confused on these seemingly random syntax changes.

Comment: I guess you can reference a var as ${varname} but define it like that.

Comment: i don't think the syntax was changed in the last 10 years - it was so even in WebMacro (Velocity's grandfather).
Variables are defined simply using just the $ sign. The curly braces are used when reference objects and their subobject graph and to separate them from the environment: e.g. where text wold continue just at the end of the variable, so Velocity needs to now what's the text and what's the variable.

Comment: I was referring to contextual changes. Velocity use the same principles as bash and perl to fix the problem of differentiating between varname and the rest of the text.